# BASH_REMATCH empty

Tags: regex, bash, shell, trepan

I'm trying capture the some input regex in Bash but BASH_REMATCH comes EMPTY

```
#!/usr/bin/env /bin/bash
INPUT=$(cat input.txt)
TASK_NAME="MailAccountFetch"

MATCH_PATTERN="(${TASK_NAME})\s+([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})"

while read -r line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $MATCH_PATTERN ]]; then
        TASK_RESULT=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
        TASK_LAST_RUN=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        TASK_EXECUTION_DURATION=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
    fi
done <<< "$INPUT"
```

My input is:

```
    MailAccountFetch                         2017-03-29 19:00:00  Success      5.0 Second(s)      2017-03-29 19:03:00
```

By debugging the script (VS Code+Bash ext) I can see the INPUT string matches as the code goes inside the IF but BASH_REMATCH is not populated with my two capture groups.

I'm on:

```
GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

What could be the issue?

LATER EDIT

---

**Accepted Answer**

Accepting most explanatory answer.

**What finally resolved the issue:**

bashdb/VS Code environment are causing the empty BASH_REMATCH. **The code works OK when ran alone.**

Comment: Answers on the bash debug GitHub repository indicate that bash version 4.4.20 addresses this problem, BUT I tried it with 4.4 and cumulative patches through 20 and I had the same problem. Here's the link -

https://github.com/rogalmic/vscode-bash-debug/issues/113

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Cyrus shows in his answer, a simplified version of your code - with the same input - does work on Linux *in principle*.

That said, **your code references capture groups  `3` and `4`, whereas your regex only defines *2*.**

In other words: `${BASH_REMATCH[3]}` and `${BASH_REMATCH[4]}` are empty by definition.

Note, however, that if `=~` signals success, `BASH_REMATCH` is never *fully* empty: at the very least - in the absence of any capture groups - `${BASH_REMATCH[0]}` will be defined.

---

There are some general points worth making:

- Your **shebang line** reads `#!/usr/bin/env /bin/bash`, which is **effectively the same as `#!/bin/bash`**.

  - `/usr/bin/env` is typically used if you want a version *other* than `/bin/bash` to execute, one you've installed later and put in the PATH (too):
    `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
  - [ghoti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1072112/ghoti) points out that another reason for using `#!/usr/bin/env bash` is to also support less common platforms such as FreeBSD, where `bash`, if installed, is located in `/usr/local/bin` rather than the usual `/bin`.
  - In either scenario it is less predictable which `bash` binary will be executed, because it depends on the effective `$PATH` value at the time of invocation.
- **`=~` is one of the few Bash features that are *platform-dependent***: it uses the particular regex dialect implemented by the platform's regex libraries.

  - **`\s`** is a character class shortcut that is **not available on all platforms**, notably not on macOS; the **POSIX-compliant equivalent is `[[:space:]]`.**
  - (In your particular case, `\s` should work, however, because your Bash `--version` output suggests that you are on a Linux distro.)
- It's **better not to use all-uppercase shell variable names** such as `INPUT`, so as to [avoid conflicts with environment variables and special shell variables](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_01).

Comment: @Inian: Because the macOS regex libraries do not support `\s` - I've updated the answer to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Bash uses system libraries to parse regular expressions, and different parsers implement different features. You've come across a place where regex class shorthand strings do not work.  Note the following:

```
$ s="one12345   two"
$ [[ $s =~ ^([a-z]+[0-9]{4})\S*\s+(.*) ]] && echo yep; declare -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=()
$ [[ $s =~ ^([a-z]+[0-9]{4})[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]+(.*) ]] && echo yep; declare -p BASH_REMATCH
yep
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="one12345   two" [1]="one1234" [2]="two")
```

I'm doing this on macOS as well, but I get the same behaviour on FreeBSD.

Simply replace `\s` with `[[:space:]]`, `\d` with `[[:digit:]]`, etc, and you should be good to go. If you avoid using RE shortcuts, your expressions will be more widely understood.

Comment: It's a good point in general (and covered in my answer), but it's not the OP's problem, as he's running on a Linux distro, where `\s` therefore _is_ available.